# what triggers the webRTC API to connect to stun server

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Don't know if this example is correct
The process, call `new RTCPeerConnection()` then `createOffer()` then `setLocalDescription()`
Then I wait for `onicecandidate` take what it gives and first send the `offer` and second the `icecandidates` through the `signal server` to the other peer

Then the other peer takes the received `offer` into `setRemoteDescription(offer)` then the received `icecandidates` into `addIceCandidate(icecandidates)` then calls `createAnswer()` this gives an `answer` to put in `setLocalDescription(answer)` this triggers `onicecandidate` take these `icecandidates` with the `answer`=`offer` and send them back to the other peer

The other peer takes the `answer` into `setRemoteDescription(answer)` then the received `icecandidates` into `addIceCandidate(icecandidates)`

I think in this example the connection will work when testing inside local network but what if it doesn't because its not a local network, at what step in this example will the API call the STUN server and what other functions do I need to call if it does call the STUN server?

Answer (score 2):

I've found that one way to generate BIND requests to be sent to the STUN server right away is to set the iceCandidatePoolSize option in the configuration to be > 0.

```
config = {iceServers: [{urls:stun:stunserver.stunprotocol.org}], iceCandidatePoolSize: 1};
peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config); // pretty much starts to resolve the DNS name and sends BIND requests right away.
```

Hope this helps.

Also: [this link](https://rollout.io/blog/webrtc-issues-and-how-to-debug-them/) is chock-full of great suggestions to troubleshoot webrtc connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a STUN server in the peer connection's configuration. E.g.:

```js
pc = new RTCPeerConnection({iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"}]});
```

There are no other methods to call, provided it works on a LAN already. You should see additional calls to `onicecandidate` from this, compared to before. That's it.

Note that a couple of the things you describe happen in parallel, but in short, what triggers the browser to connect to the STUN server is `setLocalDescription`. It causes the browser's built-in *ICE agent* to kick off its candidate gathering process for this connection, and STUN is part of that.

Comment: I still can't figure this out, my code never sends anything to my local STUN server, do you have a working example where it connects to any STUN server and you can see when it happens inside "network" debug tools

Comment: Also I gotta add that my code already works connecting two different computers inside my local wifi network and it fails when one computer is on a different network but still in both cases never sends anything to the STUN server